# Spring Controller get Variables from a different Website

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

I was wondering what would be the best way to achieve the question that I have posted? So for instance if I pressed a button it would go to the controller which would go to this address https://www.premierleague.com/results and then in this address it would get the home team name and away team name. Would this be possible via Spring. Which I can then  save into the database.

Is there any tutorials, that people know off that could answer this question?
Cheers Jeff

Answer (score 1):

You want to perform a http-query against another REST-Service within your application, which of course can be done.

I suggests you to look into this tutorial by Spring: [Spring - Consuming Rest](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/)

This one should get you started on how to use the built in http-client of Spring.

Edit: The url you posted of course serves a complete website, its not a REST-Endpoint. If the premiere league offers an API, you should use that. If not you can of course request the whole webpage and scrape it for the information you need.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will have a look at that. Thanks :)